# Mysql query matching even though they have different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$search_sql = "select category_name from category where category_id='2Dresses'";
```

`category_id` is `int` type & has values like 1,2,3.. 
But with values like '`2Dresses`', it gets matched with `category_id='2'`.

Why and how to solve this? Anyone?

Comment: Update your question and show your related tables  schema .. please

Answer (score 0):

While comparing String value with int column ,MySql Automatically truncate the value which are followed by the numbers .In your example (2Dresses) mysql truncate the value which are followed by 2 . mysql will consider your query as

```
"select category_name from category where category_id=2";
```

if the string is Starting with alphabets or non numerical value surely it will not work 
for example

```
"select category_name from category where category_id='d2Dresses'";
```

mysql truncate whole string value .so it will consider above query as

```
 "select category_name from category where category_id=''";
```

It will return Emptyset...

Comment: I edited my question, actually my problem is why the string is matching with an integer column even though the column has different value